# import mysql.connector in python won't work in timer trigger azure function

Tags: python, azure, function, triggers, timer

I was trying to generate a periodic summary report in Python by timer trigger in Azure function using MySQL database.  The Python codes using import mysql.connector to get my query data to work fine on their own.  However, when I inserted this part of the code in for trigger action, I got ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'.

Both email reports generated by MySQL connector and timer trigger function work well, but it's not working when putting them together.

```py
import logging
import azure.functions as func

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.schedule(schedule="*/30 * * * * *", arg_name="myTimer", 
 run_on_startup=True,
          use_monitor=False) 
def timer_trigger1(myTimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:

import mysql.connector

bp1db = mysql.connector.connect(
host="xxxx.xxxxx.com",
user="xxxxx",
password="xxxx01",
db = 'boppwh'
)
cur1 = bp1db.cursor()
cur1.execute("SELECT COUNT(cellid) AS free FROM cells WHERE Status = 0")
result1 = cur1.fetchall()
free1 = result1[0]

logging.info('Python timer trigger function executed.')
```

Comment: Can you share your code in the question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I added the **import mysql.connector** to the imports in your code and was able to trigger the timer trigger function.

**Code :**

```py
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import mysql.connector

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.schedule(schedule="*/30 * * * * *", arg_name="myTimer", run_on_startup=True,
              use_monitor=False) 
def timer_trigger1(myTimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    bp1db = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="<server_name>.mysql.database.azure.com",
        user="<user_name>",
        password="<password>",
        db='boppwh'
    )
    cur1 = bp1db.cursor()
    cur1.execute("SELECT COUNT(cellid) AS free FROM cells WHERE Status = 0")
    result1 = cur1.fetchall()
    free1 = result1[0]

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function executed.')
```

**requirements.txt :**

```py
azure-functions
mysql-connector-python
```

**Output :**

It runs successfully and triggers the timer trigger function as below.

[image]